# io.StringIO encoding in python3

Tags: encoding, utf-8, python-3.x, stringio

I can't seem to find what's the default encoding for `io.StringIO` in Python3. Is it the locale as with `stdio`?

How can I change it?

With `stdio`, seems that just reopening with correct encoding works, but there's no such thing as reopening a `StringIO`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The class `io.StringIO` works with `str` objects in Python 3.  That is, you can only read and write *strings* from a `StringIO` instance.  There is no encoding -- you have to choose one if you want to encode the strings you got from `StringIO` in a `bytes` object, but strings themselves don't have an encoding.

(Of course strings need to be internally represented in some encoding.  Depending on your interpreter, that encoding is either UCS-2 or UCS-4, but you don't see this implementation detail when working with Python.)

Comment: Quoting "There is no encoding": What if I do `stdout = io.StringIO()`, then which encoding standard `print()` will have?

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal: Still none, since all strings you write there are still strings.  They are not encoded.

Comment: So if I use a `# coding:utf-8` in the beginning, encoding of `print("foo")` in the buffer will be `utf-8`?

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal: You are mixing concepts here.  `# coding:utf-8` describes the encoding of your source file.  String literals in your source file are encoded in UTF-8, but will be decoded to string objects while the program is loaded.  If you write such a string object to a `StringIO` instance, it will still be a string.  Again, *strings* themselves don't have an encoding in Python 3.

Comment: So if I copy the value of that `StringIO` object to `stdout`, I should call `decode(stdout.encoding)`?

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal: No, when you write a string to `stdout`, it will be encoded with `stdout`'s encoding anyway, regardless whether the string comes out of a `StringIO` or from any other source.  (I suggest to read the [Python 3 Unicode Howto](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/howto/unicode.html) to clear up your misconceptions.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. If I understand, in that case if I want a particular encoding I should set the encoding of `stdout` then.

Answer (score 6):

As already mentioned in another answer, `StringIO` saves (unicode) strings in memory and therefore doesn't have an encoding.
If you do need a similar object with encoding you might want to have a look at [`BytesIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO).

If you want to set the encoding of stdout: You can't. At least not directly since `sys.stdout.encoding` is write only and (often) automatically determined by Python. (Doesn't work when using pipes)
If you want to write byte strings with a certain encoding to stdout, then you either just encode the strings you print with the correct encoding (Python 2) or use `sys.stdout.buffer.write()` (Python 3) to send already encoded byte strings to stdout.

Comment: The other answer was already valid, but I not only wanted to tell that there is no such thing, but also "how to fix it".

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was looking for to replace `StringIO.StringIO` while maintaining `bytes` output.